# is this a variable or function

Tags: c++, syntax, declaration

I was just looking through implementation of non local means algorithm via google (thanks google for code search) and come across this function mirror.

```
template<typename T,typename U,bool N>
inline int
boundaryExpansion::helperBase<T,U,N>::mirror(const int src,
                                               const int size,
                                               const int last) const {
  const int32 alpha(src%size);
  if (alpha>=0) {
    return (((src/size) & 0x00000001) != 0) ? last-alpha : alpha;
  }
  return (((src/size) & 0x00000001) == 0) ? -alpha-1 : size+alpha;
}
```

And the line I am interested in is this

```
const int32 alpha(src%size);
```

Now what is alpha here?  A function or a variable?  What this syntax means? Is this a variable declaration?

Comment: it defines a constant of type int32 named alpha and passes in the constructor the result of the modulo operation src % size

Comment: It's a variable with an initializer (which is necessary since it is a `const` variable).  But I'm not sure I can articulate precisely why it is a variable definition and not a function declaration, beyond "a function declaration could not contain the `%` operator" or "the first token after the open parenthesis would have to be a 'type' or 'type-related' word" (see: I told you I couldn't articulate the reason properly).

Comment: It is a variable that is getting initialized to 'src%size'. Since int32 is a POD, it is same as 'alpha=src%size'

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The '%' symbol is a modulo operator which evaluates to an int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a variable declaration. A declaration of the form:

```
type variablename = value;
```

is essentially equivalent to:

```
type variablename(value);
```

This is the case regardless of what `type` is - whether it is a user-defined class or a built-in type. Note that the reverse is not always the case - the `=` syntax requires that there be an accessible copy constructor.

For similar reasons, you can cast arithmetic types using the constructor syntax, as in: `x = int(42.0);`

Comment: *"This is the case regardless of what type is"* -- Not exactly.  If `type` does not have a copy constructor, and value's type is not `type`, the latter will not compile.

Comment: Is this allowed in C or only from C++ onwards?

Comment: I was asking that I learned C and C++ in college and I had a lot of practical experience in C (not in C++)..I never come across this kind of initialization. If it is allowed in C also, then I have to brush up my C skills..:(

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, by "does not have a copy constructor", do you mean that it has a default copy constructor, or are you referring to if the copy constructor is deleted in C++11 or otherwise inaccessible?

Comment: @bdonlan: deleted or inaccessible.

Comment: oops..since C doesn't have constructors, right? Shouldn't have asked that question..Anyway thanks friend..A new thing learned makes up a good day..

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, then surely neither of the forms would compile? An explicit invocation of the copy constructor will fail just as badly if the copy constructor is deleted or inaccessible.

Comment: @bdonlan: If value's type is not `type`, then the first is not an invocation of the copy constructor, it is an invocation of the constructor that takes an argument of whatever value's type is.

Comment: They are not **exactly** equivalent, the first is *copy-initialization*, the second is *direct-initialization*.  See section 8.5 `[dcl.init]` of the standard, paragraphs 13-16.

Answer (score 3):

It is a variable declaration, and it is equivalent to this:

```
const int32 alpha = src%size;
```