# What does "new int(100)" do?

Tags: c++, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is this a variable or function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686635/is-this-a-variable-or-function)

I mistakenly used something like:

```
int *arr = new int(100);
```

and it passes compile, but I knew this is wrong. It should be

```
int *arr = new int[100];
```

What does the compiler think it is when I wrote the wrong one?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**The first line allocates a single `int` and initializes it to `100`.** Think of the `int(100)` as a constructor call.

Since this is a scalar allocation, trying to access `arr[1]` or to free the memory using `delete[]` would lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @RedX: If you're thinking of placement `new`, this is not it (the syntax is different).

Comment: @RedX: no, it will point to a dynamically-allocated address that contains the `int` value 100. You're thinking of `int *arr = (int*)100;`

Comment: @SteveJessop Or, as NPE suggested, `new (100) int`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I'm sure that would need a cast... `new (reinterpret_cast<void *>(100)) int`, so you really know you mean it.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes.  It would certainly need the `reinterpret_cast` (unless, of course, someone has provided an `operator new( size_t, int )`).

Answer (score 31):

[Wikipedia new(C++)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=New_and_delete_(C%2B%2B)&oldid=690112349) quote:

```
int *p_scalar = new int(5); //allocates an integer, set to 5. (same syntax as constructors)
int *p_array = new int[5];  //allocates an array of 5 adjacent integers. (undefined values)
```

#### UPDATE

In the current Wikipedia article [`new` and `delete` (C++)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_and_delete_(C%2B%2B)) the example is removed.

Additionally here's the less intuitive but fully reliable C++ reference for [`new`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) and [`new[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/).

Comment: @Richard but I was taught that Wikipedia isn't a reliable source!

Comment: @AlvinWong It's not, almost by definition.  The only "reliable" source (for this issue) would be the C++ standard (which is what you should cite, if you're citing anything).

Comment: Which is why I did not give +2, @AlvinWong ;-) But you'll notice that this is the only answer to this question which even attempts a citation. Since I like citations (the more so to reliable sources), I reward this behavior.

Comment: The quote refers to an [older version](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=New_and_delete_(C%2B%2B)&oldid=690112349) of the article. In the current version the description of different calls of `new` is extended but the examples are removed.

Answer (score 12):

It allocates one object of type `int` and initialized it to value `100`.

A lot of people doesn't know that you can pass an initializer to `new`, there's a particular idiom that should be made more widely known so as to avoid using `memset`:

```
new int[100]();
```

This will allocate an array of `int` and zero-initialize its elements.

Also, you shouldn't be using an array version of `new`. Ever. There's `std::vector` for that purpose.

Comment: "a particular idiom that should be made more widely known ... you shouldn't be using an array version of new. Ever" -- so why should the idiom be more widely known? ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop, good point :) Although when fixing an old codebase, it is much easier to delete `memset`s and add parentheses than to replace the `new` with `vector`.

Comment: @avakar, I still didn't get what is meant by ...  new int[100]();
somebody pls elaborate possibly with an example

Comment: @eRaisedToX, sure, but what's unclear? "This will allocate an array of int and zero-initialize its elements."

Comment: @avakar, ohk.., but what is the difference b/w new int[100] and new int[100]()   then.... ? becoz if m not wrong new int[100] also puts elements to zero (atleast in java)

Comment: @eRaisedToX, Java is a completely different language. In C++, `new int[100]` leaves the element uninitialized.

Comment: @avakar.., yeah true, got the point, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The first one creates a single new integer, initializes it to the value 100 and returns a pointer to it.

In C/C++ there is no difference between a pointer to an array and a pointer to a single value (a pointer to an array is in fact just a pointer to its first element). So this is a valid way to create an array with one element.

Comment: A pointer to an array looks like `int (*arr)[100]` and C++ can distinguish. It's just that `new` doesn't return a pointer to an array even when you allocate an array -- instead it returns a pointer to the first element of the array. The reason is that the size is part of the type of a pointer-to-array, and of course `new` can't return a different type depending what size you pass it at run time.

Comment: Should be "C++ can not distinguish between a pointer to an element of an array and a pointer to a single value."