# Trouble with listing elements in a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working on a program in c++ in which the user can add phone numbers to a list. For this assignment, we have to use pointers while dynamically allocating the memory needed. The code below works fine, except for the fact that when the program lists the elements in the pointer, random numbers are spit out. I'm new to c++ so any ways I could be pointed into the right direction of fixing this issue are greatly appreciated.

```
int *FirstArray = new int(size);
int *SecondArray = new int(size + 1);
if (size == 0) {
    cout << "Please enter the number which you would like to add";
    cin >> FirstArray[size];
    for (int x = 0; x <= size; x++) {
        cout << x << ". " << FirstArray[x] << endl;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x <= size; x++) {
        FirstArray[x] = SecondArray[x];
    }
    SecondArray = FirstArray;
    delete (FirstArray);
}
else {
    cout << "Please enter the number which you would like to add";
    cin >> SecondArray[size];
    for (int x = 0; x <= size; x++) {
        cout << x + 1 << ". " << SecondArray[x] << endl;
    }
}
size++;
```

Comment: there are no "elements in a pointer". You can derefence a pointer and then access members of the referenced object

Comment: This line `int *FirstArray = new int (size);` does not allocate an array. Replace it with `int *FirstArray = new int[size];` Same for the line below.

Comment: Please use `std::vector`

Comment: Assuming you *meant* for `FirstArray` to be an array of `int` with `size` elements, look at what happens with `size` is 0. You allocate an array for no elements, take the first `if` and then access `FirstArray[0]`. You are also iterating from `0` to `size` inclusively, your for loops in the first branch will always access an element beyond the end of `FirstArray`.

Comment: *I am working on a program in c++ in which the user can add phone numbers to a list* -- `std::vector<int> phone_list;int x; cin >> x;phone_list.push_back(x);`  You mean tthis?

Comment: To avoid pointer related defects, prefer not to use dynamic memory.  Use `std::vector` or allocate the array as:  `int First_Array[50];`, where the capacity must be a *compile time* constant.

Comment: See also `std::list` for a *list* container.

Comment: `for (int x = 0; x <= size; x++)` this will probably not work out for you unless you are allocating `size+1` space.

Comment: Since this is an assignment, you should have covered everything you need to know recently in class. In particular the difference between `new int(x)` and `new int[x]`, and the bounds of an array's valid indices. (And, in an ideal world, the fact that arrays are not pointers and pointers not arrays.)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that a std::vector would be really the better choice for such application I think learning about pointers is a good starting point to understand why the usage of std-containers is better.

The whole if(size==0)-block in your code snippet is unsafe as well as the else-scope in further consequence because FirstArray[x] reads from memory which is not allocated at least for every x > 0.
So called [segmentation faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) are then very likely in such cases though such may be defered in case of debugger friendly memory layout or other reasons.

Besides the fact that you then never had really a list but just two values refered by two single-element arrays (or just pointers) it's then clear why you get only random numbers from the memory pointed to by the pointers.
A pointer in C (or C++) is not restricting the access to succeeding elements behind the first element.
This means, that pointers can be used for either single values (which is exactly the same as an array with size == 1) and arrays with more than one element.
Some more issues...

1. Use new int[] rather than new int() because in this context curved brackets () is understood as argument list to the compiler generated 'constructor' of the data type 'int' which in case of int() just sets the value. C++ is consequently applying its type paradigms to primitive types as well and not only classes. See [another SO article on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797926/what-does-new-int100-do)
   Using new int[size] instead does what you want. It allocates memory for an integer array with 'size' elements and returns the pointer to the first element.
2. I think you do not need a SecondArray. A statement like "SecondArray = FirstArray" is anyway not copying the elements. It's copying the pointers and leaving the memory allocated to SecondArray behind as a memory leak.
3. Deleting then FirstArray with "delete (FirstArray)" makes it even worse because then you delete FirstArray and SecondArray at once because both point to the same memory location and any further access to SecondArray would be dangerous (segfault etc.)
4. Incrementing size++ at the end is as well in vain (if I got your idea right) because the size should be clear before you allocate and access the memory, not afterwards.
5. Resizing the array in case that 'size' changes can be done either by calling new(FirstArray)[size] (which is seldomly used directly but common in std-containers) or by consequently giving up using C++ and switching to the ANSI C style with malloc() for initial allocation, realloc() for resizing, memcpy() for copying/assignment and finally free() for deallocation. But switching to ANSI C style in this case doesn't mean that you are not allowed to use it in a C++ context. BTW, in most standard C++ frameworks the new-operator and the delete-operator call malloc() and free() behind the scenes.

At the end of the day, using [std::vector<>](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm) can make life MUCH easier ;-)