# Dynamic memory allocaion in c++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I came across two similar statements but could not exactly find the diference between them. The statements are:

```
int *p = new int(75);
int *p = new int[75];
```

Can anyone help me in knowing the difference between the above two statements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "new int(100)" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797926/what-does-new-int100-do)

Comment: @ShadowMitia: Please vot to close as duplicate as it seems exactly the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The first returns a pointer to the integer with value of 75, but the second returns a pointer to the array of 75 integers, which don't have a value.